# Node.js Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am getting the following error in my terminal:

```
if (VALID_OPTIONS.indexOf(key) === -1) throw new Error(`\`${key}\` is an invalid option.`);
```

Here is my code:

[image: code image]

And this is the error that I am getting:

[image: error image]

Answer (score 2):

The actual error you are getting is the following:
`Error: 'useCreateIndex' is an invalid option.`

Which is caused by line 31:

```
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);
```

`useCreateIndex` in Mongoose 6 and above always defaults to true and cannot be set.

From the docs:

> useNewUrlParser, useUnifiedTopology, useFindAndModify, and useCreateIndex are no longer supported options. Mongoose 6 always behaves as if useNewUrlParser, useUnifiedTopology, and **useCreateIndex** are true, and useFindAndModify is false. Please remove these options from your code.

For future reference, the actual error is denoted by the `Error:` keyword and everything after it, the part above just indicates what code invoked an error to be thrown manually.

Comment: Skully, I do understand the error is in line 31. But what is it? I mean it is set as "true"

Comment: Remove the line entirely, it is not needed in the version of Mongoose you are using.

Comment: Thanks Skully. It worked. I'm just stating to be comfortable with this.